# No "theorem" counter defined in ntheorem

Tags: theorems, counters, ntheorem

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm,right=2.00cm,top=2.45cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amscd,color,enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,framed,latexsym,multicol,pstricks,slashed,xcolor}
\usepackage[amsmath,framed,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
\lhead{\leftmark}
\rhead{\rightmark}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\qed}{\qedsymbol{\blacksquare}}

\theoremstyle{marginbreak}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}\theorembodyfont{\slshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\diamondsuit}}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[Theorem]

\theoremstyle{changebreak}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\heartsuit}}
\theoremindent0.5cm
\theoremnumbering{greek}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}

\theoremindent0cm
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\spadesuit}}
\theoremnumbering{arabic}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}

\theoremstyle{change}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\ast}}
\theoremseparator{}
\newtheorem{exm}{Example}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\clubsuit}}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theoremprework{\bigskip\hrule}
\theorempostwork{\hrule\bigskip}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}

\theoremheaderfont{\sc}\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremseparator{}
\theoremsymbol{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\theoremstyle{change}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\ast}}
\theoremseparator{}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}

\theoremclass{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{break}
\theoreminframepreskip{0pt}
\theoreminframepostskip{0pt}
\theoremframepreskip{1cm}
\theoremframepostskip{1cm}
\theoremstyle{break}
\def\theoremframecommand{%
\psshadowbox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue,linecolor=black]}
\newshadedtheorem{sthm}[Theorem]{Theorem}

\theoremclass{Proof}
\theoremstyle{nonumberbreak}
\shadecolor{red}
\def\theoremframecommand{%
\psshadowbox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red,linecolor=black]}
\theoremsymbol{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}
\newshadedtheorem{sproof}{Proof}

\title{Calculus Notes}
\author{}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

chapter{Limits}
\begin{sthm}[Basic Limits]
    Let $b$ and $k \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $n$ be a positive integer. Then:
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item $\lim\limits_{x\to c}k=c$
            \item $\lim\limits_{x\to c}x=c$
            \item $\lim\limits_{x\to c}x^n=c^n$
        \end{enumerate}
\end{sthm}
\end{document}
```

For the thm and sthm I keep getting the error:

```
No counter "theorem" defined.
```

If I try and add exam, defn, proof, arem, and sproof so far they are fine. But for thm and sthm I keep getting that error. I have tried adding the following line above my definition of theorem:

```
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Thm}
```

which results in a full compile without any errors, but without the theorem environment and no shading whatsoever. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just remove `[Theorem]`  or replace it with `[chapter] ` indicating that you want the theorem counter (here: thm)  dominated by the chapter counter (among other things, thus will reset the thm counter at each new chapter).

Comment: `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[Theorem]` tries to use the `Theorem` counter as resetting counter for `thm`. This counter is not yet defined --> Do you need this resetter at all? If no,then remove `[Theorem]`, if yes, say `\newcounter{Theorem}`, but you say what `Theorem` counts then

Comment: When I remove [Thorem] in the shaded theorem definition I get no errors but now as before the theorem is compiled and printed not as a theorem but just the math and not shaded at all...

Comment: @MichaelDykes: Your bunch of theorem definitions is confusing anyway. Perhaps you should use something like `mdframed` or `tcolorbox` to provide shaded/coloured theorems and having a cleaner interface?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I am all for cleaning up my definitions but How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for `\newtheorem` has three forms

```
\newtheorem{<envname>}{<tag>}

\newtheorem{<envname>}{<tag>}[<within>]

\newtheorem{<envname>}[<share>]{<tag>}
```

With `\newtheorem{foo}{Bar}` you're defining an environment that is numbered independently of anything else. With

```
\newtheorem{foo}{Bar}[section]
```

you define an environment that's numbered like 1.1, 1.2, 2.1 and so on, where the first number is the section number and the second pertains to the specific `foo` environment; the `<within>` part should be the name of an existing counter. With

```
\newtheorem{foo}[baz]{Bar}
```

the environment will share the numbering with the *already* defined `baz` environment (which should have been defined in one of the previous ways). The `\newshadedtheorem` command has the same properties.

In your code you're using `[Theorem]` that corresponds to no previously defined environment or counter.

The following code fixes the obvious errors, but you should rethink the numbering system (it's not clear why corollaries share the `thm` counter, but lemmas don't, for instance).

Of course, due to `pstricks`, the document has to be compiled with the `latex+dvips+ps2pdf` route, which I do with `arara`.

```
% arara: latex
% arara: dvips
% arara: ps2pdf

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm,right=2.00cm,top=2.45cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amscd,color,enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,framed,latexsym,multicol,pstricks,slashed,xcolor}
\usepackage[amsmath,framed,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
\lhead{\leftmark}
\rhead{\rightmark}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\qed}{\qedsymbol{\blacksquare}}

\theoremstyle{marginbreak}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}\theorembodyfont{\slshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\diamondsuit}}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{changebreak}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\heartsuit}}
\theoremindent0.5cm
\theoremnumbering{greek}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}

\theoremindent0cm
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\spadesuit}}
\theoremnumbering{arabic}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}

\theoremstyle{change}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\ast}}
\theoremseparator{}
\newtheorem{exm}{Example}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\clubsuit}}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theoremprework{\bigskip\hrule}
\theorempostwork{\hrule\bigskip}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}

\theoremheaderfont{\sc}\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremseparator{}
\theoremsymbol{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\theoremstyle{change}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\ast}}
\theoremseparator{}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}

\theoremclass{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{break}
\theoreminframepreskip{0pt}
\theoreminframepostskip{0pt}
\theoremframepreskip{1cm}
\theoremframepostskip{1cm}
\theoremstyle{break}
\def\theoremframecommand{%
\psshadowbox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue,linecolor=black]}
\newshadedtheorem{sthm}[thm]{Theorem}

\theoremclass{Proof}
\theoremstyle{nonumberbreak}
\shadecolor{red}
\def\theoremframecommand{%
\psshadowbox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red,linecolor=black]}
\theoremsymbol{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}
\newshadedtheorem{sproof}{Proof}

\title{Calculus Notes}
\author{}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\chapter{Limits}
\begin{sthm}[Basic Limits]
    Let $b$ and $k \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $n$ be a positive integer. Then:
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item $\lim\limits_{x\to c}k=c$
            \item $\lim\limits_{x\to c}x=c$
            \item $\lim\limits_{x\to c}x^n=c^n$
        \end{enumerate}
\end{sthm}
\end{document}
```

[image]